# In what design style do these graphic ornaments and border decorations fit?

Tags: style-identification, borders

Given the image below, that contains some graphic elements, which design style do you think that best describes the image? Can I say that the design used is Victorian? Or is it baroque? Art-deco maybe?

Please help, not very good at art unfortunately... Thank you![image]

Comment: I think it has more art nouveau traits than art deco. Welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 3):

Other than the fact that they're all "decorative" those elements don't really fit in the same classification.

The initial cap 'C' is something from the *medieval era*, used in *illuminated manuscripts*.

The rectangular border design has a *Celtic* feel to it. That does have some overlap with the medieval period, stylistically speaking.

The odd snowflake and bars corner motif has a certain *1950s-60s Americana sensibility* (aka *kitschy mid-century modern*). Same for the 'S' curve and stars border.

The swashy thing is considered *calligraphic scroll work*. That's common to the 19th century.

The circular design is also common to 19th century designs. I would call it *typographic ornament*, specifically *Victorian* era.

Answer (score 1):

Terms that would fit some (if not all) of the items:

- victorian (I wouldn't call it art-deco, though the left-most corner graphic could be)
- illuminated (the monks of the middle ages)
- ornate
- swash